# Do I need ios sdk 7.0 to develop ios 7 app in xcode 6 beta using swift

Tags: ios, ios7, swift

I'm learning swift language, trying to put together a app. My iphone is using ios 7.0, but there's only ios 8 sdk in xcode 6, I found the ios 7.1 sdk in xcode 5's content folder, do I need ios 7.0 sdk if I want my app to support ios 7.0 ?
If so, where can I find the ios 7 sdk?

Thanks

Comment: No you can run iOS 8 app on iOS 7 as long as you don't use any iOS 8 specific classes and methods. Swift is supported by iOS 7 and should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the deployment target below 8.0 (e.g. 7.0) so the app runs on your iOS 7 device. As was pointed out, you should not use and iOS 8 specific classes and methods.

Please note that you will not be able to upload your app to the app store before Apple releases the official iOS 8 SDK.